# How to get a list of the connected components of a graph using GraphX's Java APIs

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm fairly new to spark and GraphX, and I'm trying to understand how to perform the following operation using GraphX's Java APIs. I'm looking to produce a method with the following signature:

```
private <List<Graph<VD, ED>> computeConnectedComponents(Graph<VD, ED> graph){}
```

Where, given a graph with only positive degree nodes, but an unknown number of connected components, it should return a list (order doesn't matter) of graphs, where each graph is connected.

I am aware of `GraphOps.connectedComponents()` and `ConnectedComponents.run()`, but I am struggling to understand the return values. The docs list them as returning a graph of `Graph<Object, ED>` and say something about the "lowest vertex id" being returned.

Basically, I am wondering what I could do to derive this list of Graphs from the return value of connectedComponents and my initial graph.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is in scala, but should demonstrate the idea.

The returned graph will contain all the vertices, but each vertex's attribute is replaced with a VertexId (really just a Long), which can be interpreted as the id of the connected component that the vertex belongs to. It is also the "lowest vertex id" belonging to the that connected component.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
val vertexArray = Array(
  (1L, ("A", 28)),
  (2L, ("B", 27)),
  (3L, ("C", 65)),
  (4L, ("D", 42)),
  (5L, ("E", 55)),
  (6L, ("F", 50)),
  (7L, ("G", 53)),
  (8L, ("H", 66))
  )

// Vertices 1 - 6 are connected, 7 and 8 are connected.
val edgeArray = Array(
  Edge(2L, 1L, 7),
  Edge(2L, 4L, 2),
  Edge(3L, 2L, 4),
  Edge(3L, 6L, 3),
  Edge(4L, 1L, 1),
  Edge(5L, 2L, 2),
  Edge(5L, 3L, 8),
  Edge(5L, 6L, 3),
  Edge(7L, 8L, 3)
  )

val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)
val graph: Graph[(String, Int), Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)

val cc = graph.connectedComponents().vertices.collectAsMap()
cc.foreach {
  case (vertexId, clusterId) =>
    println(s"Vertex $vertexId belongs to cluster $clusterId")
}
```

Output:

```
Vertex 8 belongs to cluster 7
Vertex 2 belongs to cluster 1
Vertex 5 belongs to cluster 1
Vertex 4 belongs to cluster 1
Vertex 7 belongs to cluster 7
Vertex 1 belongs to cluster 1
Vertex 3 belongs to cluster 1
Vertex 6 belongs to cluster 1
```